# Expected no. of points?

Tags: probability

**Question:**

There are in total 64 teams and some rounds. And there are matches such that in round 1 there will be 32 matches and winning teams will be promoted to round 2 which has 16 matches. Then 8 then 4 then 2 and then a single match in final round. For each match in a given round 'n' you win 2^(n-1) points. What is the expected number of points you win given that probabilities of wining and losing are identicalThere are in total 64 teams and some rounds. And there are matches such that in round 1 there will be 32 matches and winning teams will be promoted to round 2 which has 16 matches. Then 8 then 4 then 2 and then a single match in final round. For each match in a given round 'n' you win 2^(n-1) points. What is the expected number of points you win given that probabilities of wining and losing are identical

**Approach 1:**

If we bet on each match, there will be 16 points expected. i.e 16*1 for round 1, 8*2 for round 2 and so on. So expected number of points i 16*(number of rounds) that is 16*6 = 96 points

**Approach 2:**

There are (1/2) probabilities of betting right in each round then it would be a total of (1/2)(1) + (1/2)(2) + ......... (1/2)(32) = 31.5 points

Any suggestions?

Comment: Who are "you" in relation to the teams?  Are you one of the teams and you win the points if and only if you won the match?  If so, then you wouldn't be eligible to win points for games in which you don't participate in and you don't participate in any games after having lost.  Or, are you a bystander trying to guess which team performed the best overall in that round, or something else along those lines?

Comment: I'm a bystander betting on winning teams randomly

Comment: What does it cost to bet on a team?  Are you limited in the number of bets?  Your approach $1$ answers the question if you are allowed to bet on all teams in all rounds: you're guaranteed to win exactly $96$ points.  Your approach $2$ answers the question if you are allowed to bet on exactly one team per round, and you are allowed to pick which team to bet on after seeing that round's participants.  These are completely different _questions_ hence different answers.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed we have 6 rounds: $64\to32, 32\to 16, 16\to 8, 8\to 4, 4\to 2, 2\to 1$

The probability that the team you bet wins round $1$ to round $n$ is $\left(\frac{1}2\right)^n$. And  each match in a given round $n$ you win $2^{n-1}$ points.

Thus the expected value $\sum\limits_{n=1}^6 2^{n-1}\cdot \left(\frac{1}2\right)^n$

The term $2^{n-1}\cdot \left(\frac{1}2\right)^n$ can be simplified so that it does not depend on index $n$.